# Multiplying specific character with index value in string

Tags: python, string

```
def word(s1,s2):

   index = 0
   while index < len(s1):
       if s2 in range(len(s1)):
           s1[index] = s1[index] * index
       index = index +1
   return s1


print(word("aratehadb", "a"))
```

I want the code to return `"raatehaaaaaadb"`
meaning I want it to multiply the chosen letter with the index its found at, I have tried
`res = [i for i in range(len(s1)) if s1.startswith(s2, i)]` to find the positions that the letters are at but I'm stuck at how I multiply with the index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Use enumerate

You can use [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) to obtain the index of each value, determine if the letter matches what you want to multiply and do the multiplication if required.

```py
def word(s1, s2):
    return ''.join([l*i if l == s2 else l for i, l in enumerate(s1)])

print(word("aratehadb", "a"))
# raatehaaaaaadb
```

## Closer from your first implementation

```py
def word(s1, s2):
    index = 0
    # string can't be mutated (changed) so we need to create 
    # a list to change each character string and make it bigger 
    # if needed
    l_s1 = list(s1)
    while index < len(s1):
        if s2 == s1[index]:
            # Here you can replace s1 with l_s1, we access the same string anyway.
            # Also, l_s1[index] *= index also works
            l_s1[index] = s1[index] * index
        index = index + 1
    return ''.join(l_s1)

print(word("aratehadb", "a"))
# raatehaaaaaadb
```

[`str.join()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Comment: Thank you so much! so to do this I have to create a list from my string, and then multiply and add all the items, and then return the joined list. im going to read up om this join function , but thank you for the answer.
OMG I forgot strings cant be mutated....